# Controller action not being called on button click

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP .Net core MVC 2.0 app where I implemented a shopping cart for an e-commerce site as outlined [in this video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeulQdm6GBI). In the app, user can enter search queries for items which are displayed in a table. Each item in the table can be clicked on to display another page that has additional details for that item as well as a add to cart button.

The site features for searching, displaying the item results, and the details page are all implemented as actions in one controller class while the shopping cart functionality is all implemented in a separate controller class.

For some reason, when I click on the "Add to Cart" button for an item, a url of the form `http://<hostname>/<controllerName>/<controllerACtion>/<id>`is requested, but the corresponding controller action isn't called. This is strange because I'm using essentially the same code to call the action for adding to shopping cart as I did for displaying details. For this reason, I think the issue is related to the setup of the routes.

Here is the route setup in startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=resortDeals}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "shoppingcart",
        template: "{controller=ShoppingCartController}/{action=AddToShopingCart}/{id?}");
});
```

Here is the shopping cart controller structure:

```
public class ShoppingCartController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }

    public RedirectToActionResult AddToShopingCart(int dealId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Below is the code for how the action is being called once the add to cart button is clicked:

```
<div class="addToCart text-right">
    <p class="button ">
        <a class="btn btn-success" id="cartButton" asp-controller="ShoppingCartController" asp-action="AddToShoppingCart" asp-route-id="@Model.RecNo">
            Add to cart
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

What could be preventing the controller action from being called once the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the following route because the default route will handle the shoppingcart routes as well.
`template: "{controller=ShoppingCartController}/{action=AddToShopingCart}/{id?}");`

Also, try

```
<a class="btn btn-success" id="cartButton" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="AddToShoppingCart" asp-route-id="@Model.RecNo">
```

I have removed the `Controller` word from `asp-controller` attribute

Also, change the input parameter name of AddToShopingCart method to `id` instead of `dealId`

```
public RedirectToActionResult AddToShopingCart(int id)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: If I remove the second route, how do I specify the controller for the shopping cart?

Comment: Have you tried removing the second route? As I mentioned that the default route will handle the Shopping cart route as well

Comment: Note that removing the Shopping cart route was code optimization suggestion. Actual issue was the unnecessary ‘Contoller’ word in asp-controller which was preventing your controller action method

Comment: I removed the second route and I changed the anchor tag:  `<a class="btn btn-success" id="cartButton" asp-controller="ShoppingCart" asp-action="AddToShoppingCart" asp-route-id="@Model.RecNo">Add to cart</a>` but the same issue is still there

Comment: What is the url when you click on the Add to Cart hyperlink

Comment: I think I got the reason. `    public RedirectToActionResult AddToShopingCart(int dealId)` here the input parameter name is `dealId` instead of just `id`. Just change the parameter name to `int id` and it will work. I have updated the answer as well

Comment: For some reason, it's still going to the details action from the other controller. The button were dealing was just added to a details page. That details page is linked to the "resortDeals" controller. When the add to cart button is pressed, the corresponding action from the shopping cart controller needs to be called. Wouldn't two routes (one for each controller) need to be listed in the startup.cs? Right now I only have a route for resortDeals. Maybe that's causing the issue?

Comment: I noticed that the return type of `AddToShopingCart` is `RedirectToActionResult` so are you redirecting to `resortDeals` action? Put a breakpoint inside `AddToShoppingCart` method and then browse the url `https://localhost/ShoppingCart/AddToShoppingCart/13254` and it should hit that breakpoint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173373/discussion-between-loremipsum1771-and-mohsin-mehmood).

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue after publishing on the production server, when clicking on the button there was no response and I had to submit the button using Javascript.

```
<div class="addToCart text-right">
  <p class="button ">
    <button class="btn btn-success"  onclick="search(@Model.RecNo)">
        Add to cart
    </button>
  </p>
</div>

<script>
        function addToCart(recNo) {
            document.getElementById('cartForm').action = "/ShoppingCart/AddToShoppingCart/" + recNo;
            document.getElementById('cartForm').submit();
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're doing here. Where is 'cartForm' defined?

Comment: cartForm is the id of your form <form method="get" id="searchForm">

Comment: I'm not using a form though, I just have one button on the page that says "Add to cart"

Comment: wrap your div with a <form method="get" id="cartForm">...</form> tag

Comment: For some reason, now after the button is clicked, the same detail controller action is being called instead of correct shopping cart action for adding to cart. Should a new route be added? I removed the route for the shopping cart that I initially had.

Comment: I don't think we need a `form` tag and also that shoppingcart route.